# NoMethodError: undefined method 'id' for #<Array:0x007f725c52af50>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have two models `Blog` and `Article` as follows

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :articles
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :blog
end
```

And my dashboard method is as follows: [I want to fetch all the articles of all the followed blogs in @article object]

```
@f_blogs = current_user.followees(Blog) #Socialization gem method
@f_blogs.each do |blog|
    @blogs ||= []
    @blogs << Blog.where('id == ?',blog.id).includes(:articles)
end
@articles = @blogs.map(&:articles)
```

But this returns this error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method 'id' for #<Array:0x007f725c52af50>
```

The console gives output in `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy`

How to access this array?? Need help !!

Comment: What the output of  a `@f_blogs` variable? Looks like it's an array of arrays.

Comment: [#<Blog id: 4, name: "Simple Blog", desc: "Simple Blog With Category = Sports", type_of: nil, link: "SportsLove", created_at: "2015-08-21 07:47:04", updated_at: "2015-08-21 07:47:04", user_id: 1, category_id: 1, avatar_file_name: nil, avatar_content_type: nil, avatar_file_size: nil, avatar_updated_at: nil>, #<Blog id: 5, name: "Simple Blog2", desc: "simple blog 2", type_of: nil, link: "SportsLove2", created_at: "2015-08-21 13:10:07", updated_at: "2015-08-21 13:10:07", user_id: 1, category_id: 1, avatar_file_name: nil, avatar_content_type: nil, avatar_file_size: nil, avatar_updated_at: nil>]

Comment: Have you tried passing the blog object only? For example, @blogs << Blog.where("id == ?", blog).includes(:articles)

Comment: Still not solved by this approach. It throws `NoMethodError: undefined method `article' for #<Blog::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f725b56f2c8>` may be this is because this returns ActiveRecord relation as @articles So any method to convert that relation to instance may help

Comment: BTW I have solved this issue by another approach and added an answer, it would be great if you can tell me if this approach is correct

Answer (score 1):

You can refactor this a lot as you can pass an array of id's into a where clause, like so:

```
@blogs = Blog.where(id: @f_blogs.pluck(:id)).include(:articles)
```

All together that might just look like this:

```
@f_blogs = current_user.followees(Blog) #Socialization gem method
@blogs = Blog.where(id: @f_blogs.pluck(:id)).include(:articles)
@articles = @blogs.map(&:articles)
```

Though I don't totally understand what that last `map` line is for as you've already eager loaded the articles for each blog.

Comment: It throws error NoMethodError: undefined method `pluck' for nil:NilClass

Comment: that means `@f_blogs` is nil, I'm not familiar with the socialization gem but are you logged in?

Comment: Second line of code throws error TypeError: wrong argument type Symbol (expected Module)

Comment: This command did the magic, Check my answer. Tell me if it will effect the site's performance.